# Prism WPF navigation parameter missing in ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am having problem with parameter disappearing in my ViewModel after navigating to corresponding view.

I have navigation command like this:

```
    private void EditMethod(Person person)
    {
        var parameters = new NavigationParameters {{"Person", person}};

        if (person != null)
            regionManager.RequestNavigate(RegionNames.ContentRegion, "PersonEditView", parameters);
    }
```

After clicking button, the command is invoked correctly.

In my ViewModel the OnNavigatedTo is also run, and Person object is propagated.

```
    private Person _selectedPerson;
    public Person Person
    {
        get => _selectedPerson;
        set => SetProperty(ref _selectedPerson, value);
    }

    public PersonEditViewModel()
    {
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        Person = (Person) navigationContext.Parameters["Person"];
    }
```

But when my view is displayed, the Person = null and no data is displayed. It looks like the view displayed is binded to another instance of ViewModel that do not have that data filled.

Strange thing is that ViewModel constructor is run twice, while OnNavigatedTo runs only once.

I am using Dry IoC container and Prism 7.

Comment: How do you set the DataContext of the view?

Comment: Oh, you right man! I had autowire but then during digging in properties of controls there was automatically added another ModelView specifier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to what @mm8 said in comments - by mistake I ended up with two ModelView declarations in my View:

```
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:Fitto.Core.Persons.ViewModels"

         mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
```

After removing the first one and leaving only Prism autowire everything works correct.